# How to check if a user is accessing a folder?

Tags: python, windows, directory, explorer

Basically I need to password protect a folder, but I've looked around and no software really fits what we need. I have an idea for how I'd go about it, but I can't find any way to check inside python if a folder is currently open in explorer, or watch for a folder being closed. Watchdog and Watcher seem to only be reporting information about files, and if a folder has been created/deleted. Any ideas about how to do this?

I've tried walking through open windows and using their titles to get an idea of what's open, but this doesn't work if a user is inside of a subdirectory. I was also thinking of hooking into explorer with a shell extension, but I have zero clue of where to start with that.

Comment: Windows has access rights, why invent something, that never could work yourself?

Comment: Just a rough idea. Try to rename the folder and if any process is accessing the folder or any of its content then you can't rename it.

Comment: @pss that's brilliant! I'll try it.

Comment: Hmmmm, what if I view dir contest in command prompt?

Comment: @RandyButts: access rights are the only way that works. Every thing else is not the work worth thinking about it. Or don't call it protection, call it cosmetics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pss' was right. Attempting to rename the file and testing the exception on a set interval does work if a user has a file open. It doesn't work if they just have it open in windows explorer, but that actually doesn't matter now that I think of it. Comes with the added benefit of closing windows the user left open and forgot about.